# Function isn't calculating correctly?

Tags: java

After creating three objects it is supposed to take the radius and height from the user, calculate the volume and then ask again for the next cylinder. When I run this code it does prompt me for the radius and height, but it does not calculate the volume. What am I doing wrong?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;


public class CylinderTest 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String input;
    String input2;
    double radius[] = new double[3];
    double height[] = new double[3];
    Cylinder[] myCylinder = new Cylinder[3];



        for (int i = 0; i < myCylinder.length; i++)
        {

             input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a radius");
                radius[ i ] = Double.parseDouble(input);
                input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a height" +
                        "");


                height[i] = Double.parseDouble(input2);

                myCylinder[i].height = input2;
                myCylinder[i].radius = input;

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " The volume of the cylinder is: " + myCylinder.getVolume());       
            }

    }







static class Cylinder
{
private double radius;
private double height;


public  Cylinder(double radius, double height)
     {      this.radius = radius;
            this.height = height;

}



public double getVolume()
{

    return radius * radius * height * Math.PI;


}
}

}
```

Comment: `myCylinder` is never used except for its `length`. You can replace `3.1416` with `Math.PI`

Comment: I'm sorry to say this but you are in way over your head on this one. You have to learn the basics of OOP first.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the keyword `static` for your variables and methods inside your Cylinder class. I'm not sure why you did use the `static` keyword, but `static` implies there will be only *one* instance for the whole program (i.e. it is a global variable or function) . To fix it, delete the word static in the Cylinder class's methods and member variables. You may also want to look at [Math.PI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) instead of using 3.1416 as PI.

Also, thought I'd mention, that you don't need to store the volume in a variable. Instead, you can simply return it. Unless of course you want to cache it in a variable for some reason, but seeing as you're recalculating it every call to `getVolume()`, there is no need to store the volume in a variable.

i.e.

```
public double getVolume() // notice: no static keyword in the method's prototype
{
    return (radius * radius) * height * Math.PI;
}
```

**Pro tip:** Don't use magic numbers in your code, use a variable to store the magic number. As a constant (final) variable or a regular one.

e.g.

```
 static final int MEANING_OF_LIFE = 42; // this is somewhere tucked in a class or method
                                        // static is used because the final keyword
                                        // is used and therefore isn't modified
                                        // Meaning that there is no real point to have
                                        // multiple MEANING_OF_LIFE variables, hence static

 // ...

 System.out.printf("The meaning of life is: %i", MEANING_OF_LIFE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot

```
 myCylinder[i].height = input2;
 myCylinder[i].radius = input;
```

Plus,

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " The volume of the cylinder is: " + myCylinder.getVolume());
```

Answer (score 0):

remove  the `static` from getVolume(). remove the static from fields volume, height.
To calculate you have to create a cylinder object, and get the volume:

```
Cylinder cyl = new Cylinder(radius, height);
double volume = cyl.getVolume();
```